# When I use $_COOKIE['user']; in one directory it works but not in another how can I solve this?

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", $expire);
?>
```

Comment: What ^ he said. What do you mean it's not working ?

Comment: @bensiu *what you consider - work ?: When I can receive a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cookie will only be available to the current directory and all the sub directories you set it in.

To make sure your cookie is available throughout all your directories, you can set the path parameter to '/'

So:

```
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", $expire, '/');
```

As per: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Awesome, that must be it. Thanks!